# PostScript Driver issues: "ERROR: invalid font" - where to find font download (Softfont) options?

Tags: printing, font, cups, postscript

I'm having a problem with some documents printing on my Dell C2665dnf Color MFP on macOS 10.13.x and beyond (ie, including 10.14 Mojave betas).

Sometimes a document only prints out:

```
ERROR: invalidfont
OFFENDING COMMAND: xshow

STACK:
[6.1116 13.4376 12.2276 13.4376 6.1116 12.2276 0.0 ]
(!"#$%&')
```

This appears to be a font issue from both the error and [some searching](https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Printing/Postscript-error-invalidfont-when-printing-from-PowerPoint/td-p/6844). The example from Xerox for a Phaser 8560 & 7335:

[image: xerox example]

This clearly appears to be the same issue from the explanation and the answer is to set "PostScript Pass-through: Disabled" and enable "Download as Softfont" for TrueType Font and "Bitmap" for TrueType Font Download Option... But of course these options do not appear to be available on macOS.

I've looked in both System Preferences -> Printers & Scanners AND in CUPS ([Manage Printers](http://localhost:631/printers/) & [Edit Configuration File](http://localhost:631/admin/)) with no luck at finding such a setting yet for macOS.

Any idea of how to make a similar setting change to force font downloading for PostScript printers in macOS?